# problem with Login stored procedure coding

Tags: stored-procedures

Somebody please help me by modying this code.when i retrieve the Login value through stored procedure call,though i give the correct user name and password i am getting the error message "Invalid UserName or Password" means always checking the false condition only.pls help me somebody......Here is my code.

Login.cs:

```
 public int GetLogin(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);     
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetUserLogin", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = UserName;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Password;      
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString() == UserName) && (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString() == Password))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserLogin( @UserName varchar(50),@Password varchar(50))   
AS
select UserName, Password
From Login where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password
RETURN
```

Login.aspx.cs:

```
protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = TxtUserName.Text;    
        Login lg = new Login();    
        if ((lg.GetLogin(TxtUserName.Text, TxtPassword.Text) == 1)&&(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1))
        {                      
                Response.Redirect("c1.aspx");        
        }
        else if ((lg.GetAdminLogin(TxtUserName.Text, TxtPassword.Text) == 1) && (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == 0))
        {
            Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Lbl1.Text = "<b>Sorry,Invalid UserName or Password</b>";
        }             

    }
```

Above highlighted condition always going to else condition though i give the correct input.

Comment: Hi..Now its working it was logical array index error. Instead of ItemArray[1] and ItemArray[2] should be ItemArray[0] and ItemArray[1]

Answer (score 2):

First, this looks like it could be a case-sensitivity issue; even if the TSQL isn't case-sensitive, the C# will be. But why return the password at all (in fact, youshouldn't even **store** a password - only a hash).

Personally, I'd just have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserLogin( @UserName varchar(50),@Password varchar(50))   
AS
select UserName
From Login where UserName=@UserName
and Password=@Password -- yeuch (should compare **hash**)
```

Then just check for the existance of rows; if `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0`, they are validated. Of course, `DataTable` is also overkill here, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Session["UserName"] = TxtUserName.Text; 
    Login lg = new Login();    
    if ((lg.GetLogin(TxtUserName.Text, **TxtPassword.Text**)
```

Where have you declared or assigned TxtPassword.Text ? When you are passing it to the GetLogin function, there is no value set for TxtPassword.Text . Maybe thats why its always going to the last else block since both times it fails (no value for TxtPassword.Text).

```
Session["UserName"] = TxtUserName.Text; 
Session["Password"] = TxtPassword.Text;      
    Login lg = new Login();    
    if ((lg.GetLogin(TxtUserName.Text, **TxtPassword.Text**)
```

I guess your code should add the line.

```
    Session["Password"] = TxtPassword.Text;
```

verify ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should surely be checking ItemArray[0] and ItemArray[1] rather than ItemArray[1] and ItemArray[2].

Answer (score 0):

Or is this just SelectedValue 1 vs "1", 0 vs "0"???